# Trouble calculating fps on output video stream

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have implemented real-time object detection using the Tensorflow and open cv as described in [this post](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-real-time-object-recognition-app-with-tensorflow-and-opencv-b7a2b4ebdc32) and [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/datitran/object_detector_app).

The object detection works well, but I am having trouble implementing an fps calculator.

This is the code that I have written up:

```
import datetime


class FramesPerSecond:
    def __init__(self):
    self._startTime = None
    self._currentTime = None
    self._total_number_of_frames = 0

def start(self):
    # start timer
    self._startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
    return self

def stop(self):
    # stop times
    self._currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()

def update_frames(self):
    self._total_number_of_frames = self._total_number_of_frames + 1

def elapsed_time(self):
    return (datetime.datetime.now() - self._startTime).total_seconds()

def current_fps(self):
    return self._total_number_of_frames / self.elapsed_time()
```

instead of returing a value that stays the same for the duration of the video stream, current_fps returns a value that increases throughout the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current_fps function returns a value that increases over time because the self._total_number_of_frames attribute will keep increasing, whereas the elapsed time will remain more or less constant with each iteration of the loop. Basically, the numerator will forever increase while the denominator will stay within a range, resulting in a value that increases over time.

To avoid this issue, we must either allow the elapsed time function to scale up along with the increasing frames, or use some other constant to measure our fps against. Let's go with the latter and keep a seperate counter variable.

So your code above can be rewritten like this:

```
import time  # The time module is easier for our purpose.


class FramesPerSecond:
    def __init__(self):
        self.startTime = None
        self.total_number_of_frames = 0
        self.counter = 0
        self.frameRate = 1  # The number of seconds to wait for each measurement.

    def start(self):
        self.startTime = time.time()  # Returns a UNIX timestamp.

    def update_frames(self):
        self.total_number_of_frames += 1

    def elapsed_time(self):
        return time.time() - self.startTime

    def current_fps(self):
        return self.counter / self.elapsed_time()  # We are measuring against the counter instead of no. of frames.


fps = FramesPerSecond()
fps.start()

while True:  # Your main loop.

    # Rest of your code here #
    fps.update_frames()

    fps.counter += 1  # Count will increase until the if condition executes.
    if fps.elapsed_time() > fps.frameRate:  # We measure the fps only after 1 second has passed.
        print("FPS: ", fps.current_fps()) # The frames per second. 
        fps.counter = 0  # reset the counter for next iteration.
        fps.start()  # reset the start time.
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this... although I'm not sure you want exactly this or something else...

```
import datetime

class FPS:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        ...
        self._elapsed = 0
        self._fps = 0

    def start(self, ttl):
        self._startTime = datetime.datetime.now()
        self._currentTime = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=ttl)
        # print('counter started at --> ', self._startTime)
        # print('counter stopped at --> ', self._currentTime)
        return self._startTime, self._currentTime

    def elapsed_time(self):
        self._elapsed = (self._currentTime - self._startTime).total_seconds()
        return self._elapsed

    def update_frames(self):
        curr, start = self._currentTime, self._startTime

        if curr != start and curr != 0:
            print('updatin frames ...')
            for i in range(int(self._elapsed) + 1):
                self._total_number_of_frames += i
        else:
            self._total_number_of_frames += 1

        self.current_fps()
        print("frames: {}, fps: {}, time spent: {}".format(
            self._total_number_of_frames,
            self._fps,
            self._elapsed
        ))

    def current_fps(self):
        self._fps = self._total_number_of_frames / self._elapsed
        return self._fps



if __name__ == '__main__':
    fps = FPS()
    ttl = int(input('time-to-live in seconds: '))
    fps.start(ttl)
    fps.elapsed_time()
    fps.update_frames()
```